# pass multiple checkbox value using ajax in codeigniter to the database

Tags: codeigniter

iam trying to pass multiple check box value to the database using ajax.But this code is not working,please help me to find the answer. This is my jquery and ajax

```
    jQuery(".bus-cat-drop").change(function(event) {    
    $('.check').html("");
    var businesscategoryid = $(this).val();
     hitURL = baseURL + "user/postbusiness/get_businesscategoryid/";
    alert(baseURL + "user/postbusiness/get_businesscategoryid");

        //alert(businesscategoryid);
      jQuery.ajax({
    type : "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    url : hitURL,
    data : { categoryid : businesscategoryid } 
    }).done(function(data){

         $.each(data, function(key,value) {    
    //alert(key);  
    //alert(value.value);
     /* var opt = $('<option />');
                    opt.val(value.value);
                    opt.text(value.label);
                    $('#subcategory').append(opt);
                    $('#subcategory').get(0).selectedIndex = 1; */
                    $('.check').append("<input name=check[]:checked type=checkbox>"+value.label+"</br>");
                    $('.check').push(this.value);

    }); 
    });
```

iam trying to pass multiple check box value to the database using ajax.But this code is not working,please help me to find the answer. Here is my view.

```
<form client ="form" id="bus-reg-form" action="<?php echo base_url().'user/postbusiness/DirectoryCategory/'.$userId ?>" method="post" role="form">                        
                            <div class="row">       
                            <div class="col-md-6">                                
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="company">Name of Business / Company </label>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="company" name="company" value="<?php echo $company_name;?>">

                                </div>
                                </div>                                      
                            </div>
                       <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="Category">Category</label>
                                  <select class="form-control bus-cat-drop" id="businesscategory" name="businesscategory">
                                     <option value="0">Select Category</option>
                                  <?php
                                    if(!empty($list_directorycategory))
                                        {
                                          foreach ($list_directorycategory as $rl)
                                                 {
                                                    ?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $rl->dr_cat_id; ?>"><?php echo $rl->dr_cat_name;?></option>   
                                           <?php
                                                  }
                                        }
                                       ?>
                                  </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="subcategory-dropdown">
                                    <label for="subcategory"> Sub Category [Maximum 3 subcategory]</label>
                                   <div class="check" name="check[]" >

                                   </div>        
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="Business-Offer">
                              <label for="business">Business Offer / Highlights</label>
                              <textarea class="form-control required" title="Business description" id="business" rows="6" name="business"></textarea>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="control-group col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="Tags">Tags [Maximum 10 tags]</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="tags" name="tags">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         </div>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Can u show the html section

Comment: </div>
<section class="content">
  <div class="container">     
    <div class="row">